# AWS PHP SDK ContentType not being set

Tags: amazon-s3, content-type, aws-php-sdk

When uploading to S3 via PHP SDK even after setting the correct `ContentType` S3 still shows `application/octet-stream`

```
$file = Aws::putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'types-jpeg',
    'Key' => 'current.jpg',
    'SourceFile' => 'uploads/current.jpg',
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
]);
```

File successfully uploads except that viewing the file's meta data shows  `application/octet-stream` instead of 'image/jpeg' on its `Content-Type`

[image]

Any ideas?